# How to make iterating faster?

Tags: python, numpy, loops, iteration

I have this loop:

```
for i in range(self.worldWidth):
    for j in range(self.worldHeight):
        originalValue = self.world.world[i, j]
        # Process newValue
        self.world.world[i, j] = newValue
```

When the world size is (500, 500), It runs around 10 times per second which is slow for what I'm doing, When I tried to do the same thing in C# I got triple the speed (30 times per second).
is there anyways to make it faster?

Note: These speeds are calculated without doing anything with the value

Edit: after further testing with C# I got around 10 times the speed (Just the first time was slow), But in python everytime its around 0.07sec

Comment: How does world is defined ? More precisely what is its type ?

Comment: That's about the order of magnitude difference one might expect for Python vs C#.

Comment: Why are you itearting over `i` and `j`? Why don't you iterative over `self.world.world` directly?

Comment: self.world is an object of type World, it has a field called world (self.world.world) which is the data (doubles between 0 and 1) that the worlds hold, sorry for the confusing naming

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga im not so experienced with python, can i still change the values even if i dont have the indecies, because i process the value then change it

Comment: @HamzaNasab why don't you add enough information to adequately address your question?

Comment: @HamzaNasab altough, in Python you would often just create a new list (I'm assuming you have a list of lists here).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga my bad just fixed it

Comment: **wait** you are using `numpy`??? Then you are doing this all wrong. This will be slower than just using a list of lists. Never using `numpy` like this.

Comment: Look, if you want effective advice about how to speed up your code, you need to actually tell us what you are doing.

Comment: If you can find a way to structure it so that data is in dictionaries rather than lists it's often faster processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what you are trying to do but taking the numpy tag as an indicator.  Numpy runs it's internal loops in compiled code so is much faster than using explicit Python loops.

```
import numpy as np

world = np.zeros( ( 500, 500 ) )

world[:] = 42

def test( world, v ):
    for r, row in enumerate( world ):
        for c, col in enumerate( row ):
            world[ r, c ] = v 

test( world, 42 )

%timeit world[:] = 42                                                   
# %timeit 110 µs ± 1.58 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit test( world, 43 )                                               
# 69.9 ms ± 1.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

If you need calculations these can also be much faster if they can be defined in numpy.

```
weight = np.arange( 500 )/250

def test_loop( world, weight ):
    w = world.copy()
    for r, row in enumerate( world ):
        for c, col in enumerate( row ):
            w[ r, c ] *= weight[c]
    return w

test_loop( world, weight )

def test_np( world, weight ):
    w = world.copy()
    return world * weight

np.isclose( test_loop( world, weight ),test_np( world, weight )).all()
# True  # The two results are equivalent.

%timeit test_np( world, weight )                                        
# 754 µs ± 1.71 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit test_loop( world, weight )                                      
# 172 ms ± 3.62 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

As some of the comments have hinted.  It depends on what calculations you need to generate `newValue`.  Given the potential improvements in calculation time it's probably worth exploring numpy for your application.

Answer (score 0):

maybe by declaring `self.worldWidth` and `self.worldHeight` as lists with the numbers inserted whiteout using the range keyword.
that will save the calculation of the next() number each iteration.

NOTICE - this way will cause a memory waste compared to the range option that uses calculation of the next index in the loop.

Comment: i don't understand, can you give an example

Comment: @HamzaNasab he's saying iterating over a `list` is faster than iterating over a `range` object, which is true.

Comment: Note, **`range` objects are not iterators**

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga true.
in case of `a = range(10)
next(a)`
a is not an iterator, i will fix my answer.